# TypeError: params[item].split is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Console outputs ERROR `TypeError: params[item].split` is not a function. Any help is appreciated. The best help would be to understand my error in approaching this problem.

```
routeReady() {
    this.activeRoute.queryParams
        .pipe(switchMap(params => {
            if (!params['filter']) {
                // use previous month as default
                let date : Date = new Date();
                date.setDate(1);
                date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
                this.formData.startDate = DateUtils.dateToText(date);
                date.setDate(DateUtils.getDaysInMonth(date));
                this.formData.endDate = DateUtils.dateToText(date);
            }
            ['startDate', 'endDate', 'club'
                , 'subscription', 'sold'].forEach(item => {
                if (item in params && params[item] !== '') {
                    this.formData[item] = params[item];
                }
            });
            ['courts', 'groups', 'zones'].forEach(item => {
                if (item in params && params[item] !== '') {
                    this.formData[item] = params[item].split(',');
                }
            });
            return Promise.resolve(true);
        }))
        .subscribe();
}
```

This is my error:

[image]

Comment: So what is `params[item]`? Guessing it is not a string.

Comment: what's the type of params[item]?

Comment: @epascarello  params[item] is an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code assumes params[item] is a string:

```
this.formData[item] = params[item].split(',')
```

JavaScript string's have a split method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

If it is not a string it won't have a split method and thus you will get told:

> params[item].split is not a function

To check it's type do:

```
console.log('params[item]', params[item], typeof params[item])
```

Comment: It is an object

Answer (score 2):

That's because its not a regular object. Its some angular magic thing-o.
To get the value you have to do.

```
params.get('whatever property');
```

in your case

```
params.get(item).split(',');
```

Extending what I would do in your case.

```
['courts', 'groups', 'zones'].forEach(item => {
  const value = params.get(item);

  if (value) {
    this.formData[item] = value.split(',');
  }
});
```